# Receiving empty json messages from edge device

Tags: json, azure-iot-hub, particle.io

I'm sending messages from a particle photon micro controller to a Azure IoT Hub. I monitor the outgoing messages from the particle portal and they seem to be just fine. Below is a recent sample:

```
{
  "name": "*****",
  "data": "{\"eventSentUtcTime\": \"2017-11-03 10:42:00\", \"machine\": \"x10\", \"eventType\": \"coffeeMaintenance\", \"data\": {\"category\": \"MillingPlantCoffee\", \"count\": \"24868\"}",
  "ttl": 60,
  "published_at": "2017-11-03T09:42:39.233Z",
  "coreid": "*****",
  "userid": "*****",
  "version": 37,
  "public": false,
  "productID": 1427
}
```

But when I check incoming messages from the Azure IoT Hub, they're empty except the schema. I'm using the Device explorer from Azure's github for monitoring.

```
03.11.2017 10:42:09> Device: [*****], Data:[{"data":{"count":"","category":""},"eventType":"","machine":"","eventSentUtcTime":""}]
```

I double checked the incoming messages inside a sql database, which also displays an empty json message except the given schema.

```
data,eventType,machine,eventSentUtcTime,EventProcessedUtcTime,PartitionId,EventEnqueuedUtcTime,IoTHub
Record,,,,2017-11-03T10:01:26.8295948Z,1,2017-11-03T10:01:25.7270000Z,Record
```

The access policy I'm using has all permissions checked. I don't know where to problem lies.

Comment: Which tutorial did you follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your issue is more on the Particle connector side, assuming you are following [this tutorial](https://docs.particle.io/tutorials/integrations/azure-iot-hub/).